# How can I authenticate SharePoint user credentials

Tags: 2007, development

I need to access a sharepoint application from my desktop application (written in C#). How should I pass credentials and verify authentication?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Web Services to access Sharepoint data, then this may be helpful:

"HOW TO: Pass Current Credentials to an ASP.NET Web Service"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813834

Answer (score 1):

What kind of authentication your site is setup for? SharePoint provides you Authentication.ASMX service that can be used to authenticate against the site. Keep in mind this service authenticate you against SharePoint site setup with FBA authentication.

Reference:
http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/2009/06/04/How-To-Authenticate-and-Use-SharePoint-Web-Services-in-an-FBA-SharePoint-site.aspx